# How to take a screenshot of user home screen in Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to modify the Screenshoot.java file from [this](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot) plugin to take a screenshot of user home screen instead of appView screen when the app runs in background mode. When the app goes to background mode using [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) plugin, the app continues to take a screenshot of appView even in background and not the foreground screen or user home screen.

You can see part of original Screenshoot.java file below:

```js
    @Override
 public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
   // starting on ICS, some WebView methods
  // can only be called on UI threads   
  if (action.equals("saveScreenshot")) {
   final String format = (String) args.get(0);
   final Integer quality = (Integer) args.get(1);
   final String fileName = (String)args.get(2);

   super.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     View view = webView.getRootView();
     try {
      if(format.equals("png") || format.equals("jpg")){
       view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
       view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
       File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures");
       if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
       }

       File f = new File(folder, fileName + "."+format);

       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
       if(format.equals("png")){
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
       }
       if(format.equals("jpg")){
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality == null?100:quality, fos);
       }
       JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject();
       jsonRes.put("filePath",f.getAbsolutePath());
                            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, jsonRes);
                            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
      }else{
       callbackContext.error("format "+format+" not found");
       
      }

     } catch (JSONException e) {
      callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
      
     } catch (IOException e) {
      callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
      
     }
    }
   });
   return true;
  }
  callbackContext.error("action not found");
  return false;
 };
```

After some research, I have tried to change the code:

```html
View view = webView.getRootView();
```

to code:

```js
View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

but it gives an error that method getWindow() can not found even after I insert:

```js
import android.view.Window;
```

Then I changed the code to:

```js
View view = cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

The above code compiles but still captures the app screen even if it's running in background and not the user home screen.

Any help to figure out how to get the "view" of user home screen instead of app screen when the app is in background mode?

Regards.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @wscoder  were you able to find a solution?